# SQL How to select consecutive rows based on the identical value of 3 columns?

Tags: sql, duplicates, rows

I have a table transactions. I need to select only rows having the same_value more than once consecutively for the same id,type and pki. The selection should contain the following:

1. **First order the data by transactiontimestamp. The order of the rows should only depend on that order by (*NO PARTION BY, ELSE THE ORDER WILL CHANGE*)**
2. **Check if the CONSECUTIVE rows have identical values for the columns id,type and pki**
3. ** If 2 is true, check if the difference between transactiontimestamp is not more than 4 hours**
4. **If true, select current and next row**

Code to create table and data

```
create table "transaction"(
'id' varchar(80),
'transactiontimestamp' datetime2(7),
'transactionid' varchar(20),
'transactionreference' varchar(20),
'type' varchar(20),
'pki' varchar(20), 'pkp' varchar(20));

insert into 'transaction'
values
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-11T13:42:10.0000000','448','orq','YRT','6432','2433'),
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-11T13:42:13.0000000','1431','orq','YRT','6432','2433'),
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-11T13:42:17.0000000','1432','orq','TIX','6432','2433'),
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-11T13:42:19.0000000','449','orq','YRT','6432','2433'),
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-11T13:42:23.0000000','1433','orq','TIX','6432','2433'),
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-11T13:42:28.0000000','419','orq','YRT','6432','2433'),
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-11T13:42:31.0000000','40','orq','YRT','6432','2433'),
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-11T13:42:46.0000000','1434','orq','TIX','6432','2433'),
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-11T13:42:48.0000000','450','orq','YRT','6432','2433'),
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-11T23:42:50.0000000','1435','orq','YRT','6432','2433'),
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-12T01:42:50.0000000','587','orq','YRT','6432','5342'),
('7b787e6c1885dsf35','2022-03-25T11:09:05.0000000','555','orq','TIX','6432','5342');
```

My query to create selection:

```
WITH dupvals AS 
(
   SELECT
      [id],
      [transactiontimestamp],
      [transactionid],
      [transactionreference],
      [type],
      [pki],
      [pko],
      Previd = Lag(t.id, 1) OVER ( 
   ORDER BY
      t.transactiontimestamp),
      Prevtype = Lag(t.type, 1) OVER ( 
   ORDER BY
      t.transactiontimestamp),
      Prevpki = Lag(t.pki, 1) OVER ( 
   ORDER BY
      t.transactiontimestamp),
      Prevtransactiontimestamp = Lag(t.transactiontimestamp, 1) OVER ( 
   ORDER BY
      t.transactiontimestamp),
      Nextid = Lead(t.id, 1) OVER ( 
   ORDER BY
      t.transactiontimestamp),
      Nexttype = Lead(t.type, 1) OVER ( 
   ORDER BY
      t.transactiontimestamp),
      Nextpki = Lead(t.pki, 1) OVER ( 
   ORDER BY
      t.transactiontimestamp),
      Nexttransactiontimestamp = Lead(t.transactiontimestamp, 1) OVER ( 
   ORDER BY
      t.transactiontimestamp) 
   FROM
      "transaction" t
)
SELECT
   v.[id],
   v.[transactiontimestamp],
   v.[transactionid],
   v.[transactionreference],
   v.[type],
   v.[pki],
   v.[pko] 
FROM
   dupvals v 
WHERE
   (
(v.id = v.Previd 
      AND v.type = v.Prevtype 
      AND v.pki = v.Prevpki
      AND (
            v.transactiontimestamp BETWEEN v.Prevtransactiontimestamp and DATEADD(hour, 4, v.Prevtransactiontimestamp)
         )) 

      OR 
      (
         v.id = v.Nextid 
         AND v.type = v.Nexttype 
         AND v.pki = v.Nextpki 
         And 
         (
            v.Nexttransactiontimestamp BETWEEN v.transactiontimestamp and DATEADD(hour, 4, v.transactiontimestamp)
         )
      ));
```

After order by transactiontimestamp I get the following output and I marked the selection that I need.

**I expect a selection of 7 rows, but my query output result only in 6 rows, can anybody help?**

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63QAN.jpg)

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: I strongly suggest trying the exact code in your question, either locally or in dbfiddle.uk The reason being that you have typos (pkp vs pko) and at present it ***does*** return 7 rows.https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=72caa6ad26753d50f191934abac76361

Comment: @MatBailie, thx., indeed it works, but there is one exception. If the time diff is in 4 hours, but the consecutive timestamps are on two different days, it will not work.

Comment: Make a dbfiddle to prove it. Because from where I stand, your problem doesn't exist, for example see here; https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f8f51835161c3b693b3f260ff213dc3 Please ***ensure*** you can demonstrate any problems with an example in dbfiddle, then include a link to that fiddle. Without it, you're wasting everyone's time, including your own.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LAG()` and `LEAD()` to compare the rows and find duplicates. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    case when id = lag(id) over(order by transactiontimestamp)
          and type = lag(type) over(order by transactiontimestamp)
          and pki = lag(pki) over(order by transactiontimestamp)
          and transactiontimestamp <= 
           dateadd(hour, 4, lag(transactiontimestamp) over(order by transactiontimestamp))
           or id = lead(id) over(order by transactiontimestamp)
          and type = lead(type) over(order by transactiontimestamp)
          and pki = lead(pki) over(order by transactiontimestamp)
          and transactiontimestamp <= 
           dateadd(hour, 4, lead(transactiontimestamp) over(order by transactiontimestamp))
    then 1 else 0 end as same_value
  from t
) x
where same_value = 1
order by transactiontimestamp
```

Result:

```
 id                 transactiontimestamp         transactionid  transactionreference  type  pki   pkp   same_value 
 ------------------ ---------------------------- -------------- --------------------- ----- ----- ----- ---------- 
 7b787e6c1885dsf35  2022-03-11 13:42:10.0000000  448            orq                   YRT   6432  2433  1          
 7b787e6c1885dsf35  2022-03-11 13:42:13.0000000  1431           orq                   YRT   6432  2433  1          
 7b787e6c1885dsf35  2022-03-11 13:42:28.0000000  419            orq                   YRT   6432  2433  1          
 7b787e6c1885dsf35  2022-03-11 13:42:31.0000000  40             orq                   YRT   6432  2433  1          
 7b787e6c1885dsf35  2022-03-11 13:42:48.0000000  450            orq                   YRT   6432  2433  1          
 7b787e6c1885dsf35  2022-03-11 13:42:50.0000000  1435           orq                   YRT   6432  2433  1          
 7b787e6c1885dsf35  2022-03-11 16:42:50.0000000  587            orq                   YRT   6432  5342  1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=27ff53c1dc166d2013694d354ab33c2f).

Comment: thx, why should I order by timestamp in the end again? Also there is one exception. If the time diff is in 4 hours, but the consecutive timestamps are on two different days, it will not work. For example 2022-03-11T23:30:30 and 2022-03-12T01:30:30.

Comment: @Abashirsoldom Please provide a link demonstrating that it doesn't work. For example, when I edit the demo fiddle given here, it works fine. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23338c9a8334e877b83808ea575b65a7

Comment: @Abashirsoldom You're correct, this answer has a pair of typos. In the second timestamp comparison, I changed it to >= and -4 hours. The output then matches your query's output. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60572757e4637a821f1fcdc28dce2785

Comment: @MatBailie and I added two extra rows at the beginning and somehow the second row (timestamp '2022-02-14T18:10:35.0000000') is selected, while it is NOT part of the requirements. Also I added row 7-10. Somehow row 10 is selected (2022-03-11T18:45:13.0000000), while row 9 has not the same value for column type. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5942580922f2d1cea6c97d86c0dbef82

Comment: @Abashirsoldom That's the same bug. I've added your modified test data to the fiddle in my comment above, and both queries still match, after the bug fix; https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87527a84468aab44f5873f90e041d8ec. (And remember I'm not the author of this answer.)

Comment: @MatBailie thx for all your support. I think we are almost there, the only thing if I insert a new row with a different type, then less rows are selected(2 instead of 4). Check in the following link the comparison where I added 1 extra row with different type. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2840584d322816cc2269f58737a17702

Comment: @Abashirsoldom Yes, because even though you put that new row first, its timestamp is what actually matters, and that timestamp is in between the two rows the are no longer selected. The query is behaving correctly. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cbf0f9b3c2cefaea95f35b4942cb3f6f

Comment: @MatBailie totally missed that one, you are truly a champ. This is my first post on stackoverflow, how do I mark my problem as resolved?

Comment: @Abashirsoldom Use the tick next to your chosen answer.